# display options as buttons in daterangepicker

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, daterangepicker

I am using bootstrap daterangepicker http://www.daterangepicker.com/#options I would like to hide the input box and display all the range boxes in a line.

I am after something like following

```
var today = new Date();
    var dd = today.getDate();
    var mm = today.getMonth()+1; //January is 0!
    var yyyy = today.getFullYear();

    if(dd<10) {
        dd='0'+dd
    } 

    if(mm<10) {
        mm='0'+mm
    } 

    today = dd+'/'+mm+'/'+yyyy;

    today = new Date();
    var yesterday = new Date(today);
    yesterday.setDate(today.getDate() - 1); //setDate also supports negative values, which cause the month to rollover.

    var dd = yesterday.getDate();
    var mm = yesterday.getMonth()+1; //January is 0!

    var yyyy = yesterday.getFullYear();
    if(dd<10){dd='0'+dd} if(mm<10){mm='0'+mm} yesterday = dd+'/'+mm+'/'+yyyy;

    var sevenDays = 7; // Days you want to subtract
    var date = new Date();
    var last = new Date(date.getTime() - (sevenDays * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
    var dd =last.getDate();
    var mm=last.getMonth()+1;
    var year=last.getFullYear();
    //console.log(last);
    sevenDays = dd+'/'+mm+'/'+year;

    $('#reportrange').daterangepicker({
        "showDropdowns": true,
        "showWeekNumbers": true,
        "autoApply": true,
        "locale": {
            "format": "DD/MM/YYYY",
            "separator": " - ",
            "applyLabel": "Apply",
            "cancelLabel": "Cancel",
            "fromLabel": "From",
            "toLabel": "To",
            "customRangeLabel": "Custom",
            "daysOfWeek": [
                "Su",
                "Mo",
                "Tu",
                "We",
                "Th",
                "Fr",
                "Sa"
            ],
            "monthNames": [
                "January",
                "February",
                "March",
                "April",
                "May",
                "June",
                "July",
                "August",
                "September",
                "October",
                "November",
                "December"
            ],
            "firstDay": 1
        },
        "startDate": "12/02/2015",
        "endDate": "12/08/2015"
    }, function(start, end, label) {
      console.log("New date range selected: ' + start.format('YYYY-MM-DD') + ' to ' + end.format('YYYY-MM-DD') + ' (predefined range: ' + label + ')");
    });


    function cb(start, end) {
        $('#reportrange span').html(start + ' - ' + end);
    }
    cb(sevenDays, yesterday);



    $("#today").click(function() {
        console.log(this);
        //$("#reportrange").daterangepicker("show"); 
        //fix format before parsing
        var dd = today.getDate();
        var mm = today.getMonth()+1; //January is 0!
        var yyyy = today.getFullYear();

        if(dd<10) {
            dd='0'+dd
        } 

        if(mm<10) {
            mm='0'+mm
        } 

        today = dd+'/'+mm+'/'+yyyy;
        cb(today, today);
    });

<div id="today" class="btn hoverDiv red-btn" style="display: inline-block;">Today</div>
                                        <div id="yesterday" class="btn hoverDiv red-btn" style="display: inline-block;">Yesterday</div>
                                        <div id="sevendays" class="btn hoverDiv red-btn" style="display: inline-block;">Last 7 Days</div>
                                        <div id="lastmonth" class="btn hoverDiv red-btn" style="display: inline-block;">Last Month</div>                                            
                                        <div id="reportrange" class="pull-right btn hoverDiv red-btn" style="display: inline-block;">
                                            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar fa fa-calendar"></i>&nbsp;
                                            <div id="customdate" style="display: inline-block;">Custom</div>
                                            <span></span> <b class="caret"></b>
                                        </div>
```

I would like to hide the date values in the `span` tag

Answer (score 0):

It appears that, as written, the datepicker must be attached to an input, div, or span tag.

You could do something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#datepicker").datepicker({
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
})
.hide()
.click(function() {
  $(this).hide();
});

    $("#datepickerImage").click(function() {
       $("#datepicker").show(); 
    });
 });
</script>
```

Comment: what is `datepickerImage`?

Comment: It could be any image. Was thinking it was another way of getting rid of the input box. For instance you can create an image with the years on it and then when someone clicks the button the daterangerpicker will pop up.

Comment: what if i used a div with text on it. Can i use the predefined example - use the ranges as div boxes with click events and the custom will show calendar?